# How to DeleteDuplicates from a list of Rules having set to different values whereby we wish to drop the last occurrence?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, replacement, filtering, options

#### About This Function

This will eventually set default values for Options based on the end users preferences so that no `OptionsPattern` need ever be set. The symbol`FreshPreferences` handler for a list of rules should take precedence over `stdops` (standard options) and all other occurrences should be deleted. Of course all Options can still be set the standard way when this is applied to a definition.

#### The Buggy Code

I feel like I am very close to a solution but it barely misses as it works for the other cases (Returns).

```
ClearSystemCache[]
Remove@"Global`*"

FreshPreferences = {"presave" -> True, "dockedcells" -> False, 
   "cleanslate" -> False};
freshopts[pref_ : FreshPreferences] := With[{
    stdops = {"nb" -> EvaluationNotebook[], "presave" -> False, 
      "prebackup" -> True, "quit" -> False, 
      "clearsystemcache" -> True,  "removetasks" -> Tasks[All], 
      "taggingrules" -> True, "clearinout" -> True, 
      "dockedcells" -> True, "clearall" -> "Global`*", 
      "remove" -> "Global`*", "cleanslate" -> True, 
      "alertcomplete" -> True},
    lenp = If[ListQ@pref, Length@pref, 0]
    },
   If[lenp == Length@stdops, Return@pref];
   If[lenp == 0, Return@stdops];
   Return@DeleteDuplicates@Join[pref, stdops]
   ];
freshopts[]
```

#### The Ideal Output

Below is the ideal output. Notice how there are no duplicate rule pattern names in the rules.

```
{"presave" -> True, "dockedcells" -> False, "cleanslate" -> False,  
"nb" -> EvaluationNotebook[], "prebackup" -> True, "quit" -> False,
"clearsystemcache" -> True, "removetasks" -> Tasks[All],
"taggingrules" -> True, "clearinout" -> True, "clearall" ->
"Global`*", "remove" -> "Global`*", "alertcomplete" -> True}
```

#### The Actual Output

Below is the actual output. Notice how there duplicate rule pattern names in the rules. These should be deleted: `{"presave" -> False, "dockedcells" -> True, "cleanslate" -> True}`.

```
{"presave" -> True, "dockedcells" -> False, "cleanslate" -> False,  
"nb" -> EvaluationNotebook[], "presave" -> False, "prebackup" -> True,
"quit" -> False, "clearsystemcache" -> True, "removetasks" -> Tasks[All],
"taggingrules" -> True, "clearinout" -> True, "dockedcells" -> True,   
"clearall" -> "Global`*", "remove" -> "Global`*",   "cleanslate" -> True,
"alertcomplete" -> True}
```

Comment: replace `DeleteDuplicates` with `DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]`?

Comment: @kglr thank you so much. i knew about that special symbol but forgot about it. :)

Comment: how about `<|oldList, freshList|>`?

Comment: @Kuba i <3 how you sneak up on us with a 2 inch solution lol